# No AuthenticationEntryPoint could be established. Please make sure you have a login mechanism configured through the namespace

Tags: spring-security, header, response

I am using Spring-security 4.0.4.
I was trying to set the security configurations for the response headers as below-

    `<sec:http use-expressions="true">
        <sec:headers defaults-disabled="true"/>
    </sec:http>`

This setting is to disable the security components in the security header.
However, if this setting is done then the following exception is thrown during the server startup.

    `Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: No AuthenticationEntryPoint could be established. Please make sure you have a login mechanism configured through the namespace (such as form-login) or specify a custom AuthenticationEntryPoint with the 'entry-point-ref' attribute`

As per the error, the settings requires `form-login` to be used with the above setting.Could someone please let me know why it is so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`authentication entry point` (i.e. where the authentication process is triggered by an attempt by an unauthenticated user to access to a secured resource)

You can config the `entry-point-ref` for you own entry point that implements `AuthenticationEntryPoint`， like following config

```
<http entry-point-ref="youOwnEntrypoint">
```

Or you can just set the `auto-config` to true, it will register a login form, BASIC authentication, logout services automatically.

```
<http auto-config="true" >
```